# How do I get the scope attribute on my table headers when using MyFaces 1.1?

Tags: java, web-applications, facelets, myfaces

I'm using MyFaces 1.1.7 with Facelets and Tomahawk.

When creating a regular data table, like:

```
<h:dataTable value = "#{Datamanager.data}" var = "row">
   <h:column>
        <f:facet name = "header">
            <t:div>
                <h:outputText value = "Name" />
            </t:div>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value = "#{row}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I get a HTML generated table with a header like:

```
<table>

 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
    <div id="j_id4:j_id6">Name</div>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody id="j_id4:tbody_element">
  <tr><td>First</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Second</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

However, to conform with WAI validation I would love to have the "scope" attribute on that header (even when the scope is only 1 column). Does anyone know how to add it (either by having MyFaces add it by default, or by adding an extra attribute) so that I get a header like:

```
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">
    <div id="j_id4:j_id6">Name</div>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
```

I have tried using  like:

```
<f:facet name = "header">
    <f:attribute name="scope" value="col" />
<h:outputText value = "Name" />
</f:facet>
```

with no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in MyFaces 1.2